# ng build error in cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have a project that builds on other machines, but it won't build on a new machine that I am setting up.  I have nodejs installed, I have the angular cli installed, typescript, I have run npm update, I keep getting this error, but there is not stacktrace to tell me where it is and I can't find this anywhere in the project, which tells me it must be something else.

Is this something specific or is there something else that I can try?

[image]

Comment: npm install all, ng --serve --aot

Comment: it got a little further and then gave the same error and said that webpack failed to compile.  I have the same version of webpack installed as the other machine.  3.11.0

Comment: are you using some lazy routes?

Comment: No I am not.  I did blow away all of my node_modules and then did a npm install.  That got me the same results.

Comment: share ur code with us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps worked for me:

1. delete `package_locked.json`
2. delete `node_modules` folder
3. rerun `npm install`

Then `ng build --prod` was successful.

Comment: I used these steps from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10131#issuecomment-409766290 for @angular/core : 7.0.0. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when changing the branches and there have been many changes. Try to restart the client server with *ng serve* or *node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve* (in my case). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if all fails after these please confirm your tsconfig.app.json
does it have "types": ["node"] or any other parameter. types should be empty